# How can I run multiple instances of a SQL Server stored procedure in parallel

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I need to run a stored procedure with different parameters each time - there is no data overlap but some temp tables are being created and dropped inside the procedure.

I am calling it via ADF stored procedure activity which is being called in a for each loop.

For now - I am running it sequentially but I want to speed it up without any conflicts  - hence want to parallelize it.

How can I keep it ACID compliant (non overlapping transactions) as well as run multiple instances of it in parallel at the same time?

The query is more around: will multiple instances of a proc be triggered if I do this .. and if yes.. how can I ensure one whole run of a proc is a single transaction that creates n drops temp tables within that transaction without impacting other parallel runs?

Comment: Please don't set  isSequentially in for each active.

Comment: As already mentioned, to run in parallel, that's a simple config. How to make your SP's run in parallel without conflicts? We'd have to see the code

Comment: Not sure about ADF, but on a regular server parallelizing will not usually help as most procedures are IO-bound, not CPU-bound

Answer (score 1):

Please don't set the isSequential in for each active:
[image]